# remove div using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a message system made by myself (Its not good) and I need some help. I input some words into a box then submit it.

`<form name="input" action="messagesave.php" method="POST">`

```
$myFile = "messages.txt";
$fp = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "<div class='messages'>" . $_POST["comment"] . "</div>" . "<br />";
fwrite($fp, $stringData);
fclose($fp);
```

That saves my message, on a separate page this displays my message

```
<?php include 'messages.txt';?>
```

And on that page I want to be able to delete messages, I tried using Javascript and people told me you need to use PHP to delete it. How can I click something next to the message to delete it?

OR

Can I save the messages into a different file every time like $myFile = "messages[1 then 2 then 3 ect..]";
then open all by php include 'messages[all of them].txt'

OR

Any other better ways to do a comment system where the comment appears on another page?

Comment: there can be more than one message in that file? than how you will delete the messge.

Comment: how do u remove div message

Comment: It would be helpful to mention [what's inside of that file you're opening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676455/delete-an-entire-div).

Comment: Isn't better to use database? Doing it your way will be super painful to delete messages. Maybe save serialized (`serialize()`) array into a file and then read file, unserialize it (`unserialize()`) and then display it with HTML formatting? This way when you want to delete you can read file, unserialize, delete row in array and then serialize and put back to file.

Comment: You can also use timestamps as identifiers for your messages and save each message in separate file (file name is timestamp). This way to delete them you can just delete file with specific timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using javascript only

for example

```
<div id="message">
<?php include 'messages.txt';?>
</div>
```

And use jquery to delete specific message inside div in this text file
for example , suppose your mesage will be like that

```
<div id="submessage">Some Text Here</div>

$('#message').click(function(){
  this.find('#submessage').fadeOut ();//This will remove comment div when clicking it's    parent
 });
```

Comment: I think He is asking div inside that txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `unlink` to delete the entire file?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

```
if ($_POST['delete_file]) {
    unlink('message.txt');
}
```

Or if you knew what line the message was on in the file you could remove that line;

Comment: How could I remove the stuff on each the line because i have each div inside the message on each line

Answer (score 0):

What you need is providing id's to each div

```
$myFile = "messages.txt";

$todo = getRequest('todo', true);

switch($todo) {
    case 'add' :
        $message = getRequest('msg', true);
        if(is_null($message)) {
            //hlandle it
            echo "no message found to add!";
        }
        addMessage($message);
        break;
    case 'remove':
          $id = getRequest($id, true);
           break;
        default:
         echo 'what do you want me to do?';
    }

    function getRequest($key, $only_post = false) {

        if($only_post) {
            if(! isset($_POST[$key])) {
                return null;
            }
            return $_POST[$key];
        }
        if(! isset($_REQUEST[$key])) {
            return null;
        }
        return $_REQUEST[$key];
   }

    function addMessage($message) {
        global $myFile;
        $id = microtime();
        $div = "<div class=\"messages\" id=\"{$id}\">{$message}</div>";
        file_put_contents($myFile, $div ,FILE_APPEND);
    }

    function removeMessage($id) {
        global $myFile;
        $content_list = explode("\n" , file_get_contents($myFile));

        if(empty($content_list)) {
            return false;
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($content_list); $i++) {
            if(preg_match("/<div[^<>]*id=\"{$id}\"/i", $content_list[$i])) {
                unset($content_list[$i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        file_put_contents($myFile, implode("\n", $content_list));
    }
```